# AJAX Maile sender + Multiple Attachment + Bootstrap plugin

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, email

i just have write script for sending emails. It take random email and send with random values - all works fine. Now i just want add option to send multiple images - Select random one and send with email.

I using bootstrap and i was find this plugin: http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input

But when i try to upload images i get 405 error. Meaby do you know any other way to send attachments with ajax?

Here is my code:

```
$("#dodawarka").submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();


      var tytul = $("#tytul").val();
      var kontos = $("#lkonta").val();
      var tresc = $("#tresc").val();
      var jemail = $("#kemaile").val();
      var jemail = $("#kemaile").val();


      var dataString = 'listakont=' + kontos + '&tytul=' + tytul + '&tresc=' + tresc + '&emailjaki=' + jemail;

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "dodaj.php",
        data: dataString,
            beforeSend: function(){
              $('#tytul, #tresc, #przyciskx').prop( "disabled", true );
              $('.wczytywanie').show();
            },
            success: function(){
                $('#ddodaneok').show();
                $('#dodawarka').slideUp();
                $('#linkizwrotne').show();
            },
             error: function(){
                $('#kurwasabledy').show();
             }
    });

        return false;
});
```

And:

```
    <form role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="dodawarka" method="post">
  <div class="form-group" id="listakont" style="visibility:hidden; position: absolute;">
    <label for="listakont">Lista kont na które zostaną wysłane wpisy</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" id="lkonta" disabled></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="ssssemail" style="visibility:hidden; position: absolute;">
    <label for="ssssemail">Emaile z których będzie można wysyłam wpisy podaj w formacie</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" id="kemaile"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="tytul">Podaj tytuł wpisu <em>+spintax</em></label>
    <input type="tytul" class="form-control" id="tytul" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="tresc">Treść wpisu <em>+spintax</em></label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="25" id="tresc" required></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="obrazki">Dodaj obrazki</label>
    <input id="input-id" type="file" class="file" data-preview-file-type="text" multiple=true data-min-file-count="1">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="przyciskx"><img src="img/infinity.gif" class="wczytywanie" /> Wyślij na zaplecza</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

`<input id="input-id" type="file" class="file" data-preview-file-type="text" multiple name="files[]" data-min-file-count="1">`

Added: `name="files[]"`and only `multiple` not `multiple=true`.

And in php do:

```
$output = '';

if(is_array($_FILES)){

    foreach($_FILES['files']['name'] as $name => $value)
    {
        $file_name = explode(".", $_FILES['files']['name'][$name]);
        $allowed_ext = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif");

        if(in_array($file_name[1], $allowed_ext))
           {$new_name = $userid.md5(rand()).".".$file_name[1];

            $sourcePath = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$name];

            $targetPath = "uploadedimages/".$new_name;

            include_once("connection.php"); // your connection to DB and select DB

            $sql = "INSERT into images(userid, imgpath) VALUES ('$userid', '$targetPath')";

            $query = $conn->query($sql);


            if($query && move_uploaded_file($sourcePath, $targetPath))
            {
                $output .= '<div class="col-md-3"><img src="'.$targetPath.'" class="img-thumbnail" width="150px" height="180px"/></div>';
            }
        }

    }
}
echo $output;
```

Comment: Thanks, but need also script for send it with ajax :)

Comment: You're sending it with AJAX only friend :)  You can use the AJAX that you already have in place.